# keep any div in horizontally middle

Tags: html, css

I have two fixed sized div and I want to keep them horizontally middle even if I re-size the screen. Even if I remove one div for low screen, I want to keep other in the middle.

Here is the code I have tried...
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ask2asim/RrbLG/)

```
<div id="wrapper1">
     <div id="one">1</div>
     <div id="two">2</div>
</div>
```

CSS from here...

```
#wrapper1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper1 #one {
    width: 200px;
    height: 90px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #AAAAAA;
}
#wrapper1 #two {
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #AAAAAA;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {

    #wrapper1 #two {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/RrbLG/6/)**</kbd>

`text-align:center` into your parent div will make all the child div's will come in the center.

css

```
#wrapper1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    text-align: center; /* add just this to make child elements center in parent div */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the mentioned below css :-

```
#wrapper1 {
    display: table;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

through `display:table` and `text-align:center` into your parent div all the child div's will come in the center either its 1 or more than 1 div....

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RrbLG/2/)